# SSRS IIF Expression across Multiple DataSets

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, iif

I'm trying to do an IIF expression on a 2nd dataset to sum the 'BookingsComfirmed2016LASTWEEK' column and then divide it by the sum of the 'Stock2016Week' column in the dataset I'm in and where the PropertyTypeCategory = Cottage, but with no joy. I'm sure it's something to do with the placement of the 2nd dataset name, but would appreciate any help. Regards Claire

Dataset1 = TradingLastWeekandYTD
Dataset2 = TradinglastWeekandYTDSTOCK

=(IIF(Fields!PropertyTypeCategory.Value, "TradingLastWeekandYTD" = "Cottage",Sum(Fields!BookingsConfirmed2016LASTWEEK.Value, "TradingLastWeekandYTD")) /(IIF(Fields!PropertyTypeCategory.Value = "Cottage", Sum(Fields!Stock2016Week.Value)),0)

Comment: I think your second last ) should be at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your `iif()` won't work like this.

You can't check row by row in a dataset you're not currently working in, which is what you are trying to do with the first part of the `iif()`.

You can use custom code to do an aggregated `lookupset()` to get the values of the first part.

This link https://itsalocke.com/aggregate-on-a-lookup-in-ssrs/ will help you do the custom code.

For the `lookupset()`, you would have to do something like..

```
=Code.SumLookup(lookupset(Fields!PropertyTypeCategory.Value, "Cottage", Fields!BookingsConfirmed2016LASTWEEK.Value))
```

This assumes that your custom code function is called "SumLookup". It will sum all the values that the `lookupset()` returns.